# Update txt file content with python on Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, subprocess

```
 if len(ip) > 0: 

        #All tabs
        filename ="output"+str(ip)+".txt"
        action = 'FullExport'
        menu_action = 'all'
        arg_list = '/home/venv/upnp/bin/python2.7 /home/code/upnp/Client/UPNP_Client_Cmd_Line.py'             
        arg_list += ' --action='
        arg_list += action
        arg_list += ' --ip='
        arg_list += (str(ip))
        arg_list += ' --menu='
        arg_list += menu_action
        arg_list += ' > ' + filename
        arg_list += ' 2>/dev/null'

        time.sleep(3)

        #Deleted tabs

        filename ="output"+str(ip)+".txt"
        action = 'FullExport'
        menu_action = 'deleted'
        arg_list = '/home/venv/upnp/bin/python2.7 /home/code/upnp/Client/UPNP_Client_Cmd_Line.py'             
        arg_list += ' --action='
        arg_list += action
        arg_list += ' --ip='
        arg_list += (str(ip))
        arg_list += ' --menu='
        arg_list += menu_action
        arg_list += ' >>' + filename
        arg_list += ' 2>/dev/null'


        x = subprocess.Popen(arg_list, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')

        #Wait for all files to be fully exported
```

I am trying to update a txt file on linux. When I send second command to machine, it deletes the previous files content.

I want to export the content of #deleted tab just after all tabs in the same file. arg_list += ' >>' + filename this command does not work. Any helps, will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see the first command call, in the section  `#All tabs`.

Comment: Hi @Fomalhaut. All is just a menu action. You can export file with different menu actions.

Comment: Hi @yakupme I am not sure, everything is clear enough in your description. Could you, please, provide step-by-step an exact code and what you're doing, and also the actual and desirable results.

Comment: hi @Fomalhaut. thanks for your help. I just export in two files. That works fine for right now.